# Jeep Wrangler Sahara (86,600kms mileage)-Oil change

Tags: engine, oil-change

Is it okay to mix Mopar 5W-20 with 1.5 liter of Total Quartz 5W-40?  Driving in the middleast

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/2891/675

Comment: And why would you want to?

Comment: The question listed as a duplicate refers specifically to a Wankel rotary engine, and doesn't take place in the Middle East where driving conditions could change the answer.

Comment: I normally take the jeep to garage to have the oil change, however, I had short of Mopar 5W-20 oil, so the shop added some 1.5 liters of Total  Quartz 5W-40.  I was only worried about the engine.